# Two List Comparison in Excel

Tags: excel

I have in excel

[image: two lists]

I need a way to compare the values in the second column of the left list to see if they're higher or lower than the corresponding value in the right-most list - based on the value of the first column.

For example:

[image: Something like this]

I'm having trouble since the left list contains duplicates in its first column whereas the right list has only unique values in its first column.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code yet?

Comment: Yes, however I've basically scrapped it since it was totally useless.  I'm not even sure where to start with this one!

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you show some code.

Comment: Why are the duplicates in the first list a problem? It seems a simple lookup formula to get the value in the right column should do what you describe.  What have you tried?